# Normal Quadratic Forms and Noncentral Chi Squared

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

If $Y\sim N(\mu,\mathtt{V})$ and $\mathtt{A}$ is symmetric then prove that
\begin{equation}
Y^\top\mathtt{A}Y\sim\chi_{r,\mu^\top A\mu}^2\text{ if and only if }\mathtt{AV}\text{ is idempotent of rank }r\text{. }
\end{equation}

$\chi_{r,\mu^\top\mathtt{A}\mu}^2$ represents the noncentral chi squared distribution with $r$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality $\mu^\top\mathtt{A}\mu$.

#### What I have tried

I know that $Y=\mathtt{B}Z+\mu$, where $Z\sim N(0,\mathtt{I})$ and $\mathtt{B}$ is a regular matrix such that $\mathtt{BB}^\top=\mathtt{V}$, then I concluded that
\begin{equation}
Y^\top \mathtt{A}Y=Z^\top\mathtt{B}^\top\mathtt{AV}\mathtt{B}^{-\top}Z+2\mu^\top\mathtt{AB}Z+\mu^\top\mathtt{A}\mu\text{, }
\end{equation}
I this point I tried to expand some terms using the idempotency of $\mathtt{AV}$, but it seems to be a dead end, also, I can't figure out how to use the rank hypothesis.

Comment: Look at Section A.2 [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119432036.app1).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188626/119261, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740842/321264